# Create a fast moving plant overlay for driving scene

Tags: premiere

I have footage of someone driving a bike along a street in side view. I´d like it to appear more fast moving, like I filmed it through plants and trees which are moving swiftly across the screen. Kind of similar to 3:10 - 3:12 in this video

I was thinking of a stock video of cut-out vegetation that is moving swiftly and blurry across the screen and overlaying it on my footage. What would be your suggestion on how to do this? I have access to storyblocks, perhaps also enavto elements later.
Oh and I´m using premiere pro.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in After Effects, not Premiere. It's better suited to [compositing video effects](https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/compositing-special-effects-in-after-effects) (which is what this is).

You might get away with a lot of static foreground imagery of trees as a matte which flies past quickly, assuming the shot is as short as the one shown in the youtube video.

You would need to overlay the matted tree images over the footage, and keyframe its position, so that it moves across the screen rapidly and convincingly with the motion of your camera.  Make sure motion blur is switched on, and that it matches how the footage looks, both in terms of motion, but also colour correction.

Another [compositing tutorial here](https://www.rocketstock.com/blog/compositing-tips-adobe-after-effects/).

Answer (score 0):

The vegetation in the video is real.  There’s no substitute for that.  If you can’t re-shoot with real plants in the foreground, then the next best thing would be to shoot them on their own, matching the camera movement, lens attributes, etc, and composite that over top. Since plants are green, a blue screen would be ideal, but you might get away with a luma key, or shooting against a blue sky.

It’s highly unlikely that you’ll find stock footage that matches your original conditions, lighting, time of day, etc.